# Active subscription per month based on end date?

Tags: php, mysql

//Hi i have this mysql table

```
id    price     startDate     endDate

1     200       2012-01-10   2012-03-15 
2     250       2012-02-15   2012-03-18 
3     100       2012-02-11   2012-02-20 
4     260       2012-03-22   2012-04-15
```

What I want is to get the total amount of earnings by the subscriptions on a per month interval, so that output of this would be

```
201201    200
201202    550     //(250 + 200 + 100)
201203    710     //(260 + 200 + 250)
201204    260
```

My own sulution to this is based on a lot of php loops and temp variables, but I think that there has to be a better way?

Comment: Righ now i just get all the plane subscription form the database without any SQL magic and to the rest from php, cause I have no clue how i could simplefy it with mysq, so not much, dont knwo where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the right trick

```
SELECT YEAR(startDate)year, MONTH(startDate)month, SUM(price)price FROM table GROUP BY MONTH(startDate)
```

Comment: You may not select YEAR(startDate), since you already filtered that out with your group by clause.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois Why can I select `SUM(price)` and `YEAR(startDate)` I can't?

Comment: If you use GROUP BY in a query you can only use aggregate functions and the columns you grouped by in your select clause. Everything else will be undefined. In your case YEAR(startDate) will be ambiguous, since you could mean any startDate of all the rows in this group.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois Yeah, but in this case we are able to do in that way, since all `year/month` will be the same, the only thing that will change is the `day`, also the only one I am not selecting...

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate functions and group by:

```
SELECT SUM(price), endDate FROM table GROUP BY endDate;
```

Comment: this will just give me the sum of the month the subscription ends, i need to sum the price into each month between the startDate and endDate aswell

Comment: if i only have one subscription price:200 2012-01-01  -- 2012-09-01, it needs to  output 200 for each month.

Comment: Expanding on that query, a simple method might be just to loop through the months with a query like this... `SELECT SUM(price), endDate FROM table WHERE startDate => '2012-01-01' AND endDate < '2012-02-01';`

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it another try but this will have multiple queries:

```
$totalMonths = ($maxDateYear - $minDateYear) * 12 - $minDateMonth + $maxDateMonth;
$year = $minDateYear;
$month = $minDateMonth;
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) FROM table WHERE startDate < ? and endDate >= ?");

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalMonths; $i++) {
    $date1 = "$year-$month-01";
    if (++$month > 12) { $month = 1; $year++; }
    $date2 = "$year-$month-01";
    $st->execute(array($date2, $date1));
    echo "$date1: " . $st->fetchColumn();
}
```